# groupby multiple values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a subset of a dataframe here:

```
data = {'Name': ['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3', 'ch4', 'ch5', 'ch6'],
        'Time': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'Week' : [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]
            }

dfx = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to sum up all the times for each week so Week 1 time is 1, Week 2 time is 2+4+6, and Week 3 is 3+5.  I also need it to look through the 'Week' column and find all the different weeks, so for this example there are 3 but for another dataframe it could be 2 or 4.

End result is look through a column in a dataframe, find the unique values (1,2,3,...n), groupby be each of those values into rows and sum up the time for each of those values.

I have tried a handful of ways but nothing is really working how I would like.  I appreciate any help or ideas.

Expected Output:

```
                                 Sum
Week 1: 1                         1
Week 2: 2  4  6                   12
Week 3: 3  5                      8
```

The output can be either individual dataframes of the data or one dataframe that has all three rows with all the numbers and the sum at the end.

Comment: could you include your own tries and the expected output? It's a little unclear what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
    import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3', 'ch4', 'ch5', 'ch6'],
        'Time': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'Week' : [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]
            }

dfx = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfx = dfx.groupby('Week')['Time'].sum()
print(dfx)
```

output:

```
Week
1     1
2    12
3     8
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Is there a way to create 3 rows of each datapoint?  So Week 1 has all the values of week 1 and Week 2 has each number before it is added up.  When I remove the .sum() the resulting variable looks like: core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` "Week", select column "Time", and you can pass multiple functions (such as `list` constructor and `sum`) to [Groupby.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to do the things you want:

```
out = dfx.groupby('Week')['Time'].agg(Times=list, Total=sum)
```

Output:

```
          Times  Total
Week                  
1           [1]      1
2     [2, 4, 6]     12
3        [3, 5]      8
```